# Why is PrusaSlicer squishing filament everywhere?

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, creality-ender-5, prusaslicer

I've been using SuperSlicer for a while and I really like it, but it's unstable and crashes a lot. I want to get away from it, and PrusaSlicer looked great but every print I've done with it has this issue. It's like it lays down so much plastic that it builds up higher than the nozzle can reach, and the hot nozzle just smears it everywhere.

What should I do about this?

I'm using an Ender 5 with Creality PLA. My settings are default for both slicers, except setting the infill to 100% for the below prints. Left is from PrusaSlicer, right is from SuperSlicer.

[image: Printed dice]